# Why are my odds ratio confidence intervals so wide?

Tags: confidence-interval, odds-ratio

I'm pretty new to categorical data analysis. I'm trying to understand why my confidence intervals are so wide, I've never seen CI's this wide. From what I'm reading online this is mostly related to the small sample size. Are there other things I'm missing? I've pasted some of my output from R. I was using 'epitools'

**OR#1**

[image]

**OR#2**

[image]

**OR#3**

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The sample odds ratio is very large (20). As such, you observe an extremely strong association between the two binary variables.

But this very large value would drastically change if a single observation would be moved in or out the cell with the single observation. So, even if the sample size is moderate, the estimate is extremely unstable. This is reflected in the CI.

You can see that phenomenon in the third table: The sample size is the same. Still, the CI is much less wide as the sample odds ratio is less extreme.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the small cell counts leading to extreme odds ratios and wide confidence intervals, note that CIs for ORs are computed by exponentiating CIs for log ORs. Thus uncertainty in one direction results in a very large confidence interval.  Uncertainty in the other direction does not. In your first example the OR (CI) for sex is 20.6 (3.9, 511).  If your variable had been reverse coded the OR (CI) would be 0.05 (0.002, 0.26).  Not very wide.

Comment: Except, actually exactly as wide. Just a smaller *number*.

Comment: I get your point: the uncertainty in OR and in 1/OR is the same. However, on the OR scale, 511-3.9 = 507 is much wider than 0.26-0.002=0.26. Given the original poster's question was about the width of the interval, I thought it important to mention the effect of exponentiation.

Comment: Right, but the context of an odds ratio we can't judge the width of the interval using subtraction. 511 / 3.9 = 131 and 0.26 / 0.002 = 130 are the *same* (to within the precision we computed at).

Comment: We can't or we shouldn't? You and I agree.  Just making sure others do, too. These OR CIs all come from logOR CIs. On that scale, the CIs do have the same width.